# How to display a tree from the information stored in database?

Tags: java, tree, nested-sets

Using Nested Sets, it's possible to store a tree in a relational db. How to display the tree, with the correct relations of each node?

[image]

For example, each node's left and right values are stored in db. How to display this tree in java based on the nested set data? How to display the correct hierarchy and relations of each node only with the information stored in DB? How to display the path from the root to the node which has no children, for instance, A->B->D, A->C, A->E->F.

EIDT:

Based only on the information in the table, is it possible to display the tree like:

A

----B

--------D

----C

----E

--------F

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how this could be displayed graphically (or textually) on screen? Or how it might be handled by some sort of object in memory?

Comment: textually. My point is that how to reconstructure the tree from the database.

Comment: I don't get your question. Do you want to make tree operations directly on the database, do you want to make tree operations on Java objects, or something else?

Comment: I want to reconstruct the tree from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a class as follows:

```
class MyNode
{
    public int id; // these could (should?) be made private with getter/setter methods
    public String value;
    public int lft;
    public int rgt;
}
```

Using this you could do something like this:

```
ArrayList<MyNode> nodes = new ArrayList<MyNodes>();
// add SQL code to load values from DB
// make sure to load the nodes sorted by their lft values.
for ( int c = 0; c < nodes.size(); c++ )
{
    String result = createNodeListFor(nodes.elementAt(c), nodes);
    if ( result != null )
    {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

The missing method:

```
public String createNodeListFor( MyNode endNode, ArrayList<MyNodes> nodes )
{
    String result = "";
    // Again, this assumes the nodes are sorted by 'lft'
    for ( int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++ )
    {
        MyNodes current = nodes.elementAt(i);
        if ( current.id == endNode.id )
            continue; // skip self test
        if ( current.lft < endNode.lft && current.rgt > endNode.rgt )
        {
            if ( result == null )
                result = current.value;
            else
                result += "->" + current.value;
            continue;
        }
        if ( current.lft < endNode.lft && current.rgt < endNode.rgt )
        {
            return null; // this node is not an end node
        }
        if ( current.lft > endNode.lft )
        {
            break; // assuming the list is correctly sorted, we don't need to check any more nodes
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Something like this *might* work ... good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks. I will try it later. What about displaying the three paths: A-->B-->D, A-->C, A-->E-->F?

Comment: @Wei, It should already do that. Just not on a single line (because of the `println` call).

Comment: The reason for organizing data as a nested set is to have tree operations directly in SQL. I.e. there exists already an API to get data properly structured from the database (e.g. something like getChildren(nodeId)).

Comment: Could you please tell me the exact API or an example of the use of API? My point is how to reconstruct a tree based on the nested set in DB? Including the correct hierarchy.

Comment: @Way, did the above _hack_ not work? Or you haven't tried it yet? I'm just curious as to whether it worked or not!?

Comment: @Way, great to hear that it worked ... a green tick would be nice ;)

Comment: Hi @munyul ; what is `n.value` ?

Comment: Hi @Tiana987642, `n.value` is a typo, it should be `current.value` - these things happen when you write the code on with fly without a compiler...