# Change parent property according to children property in a Nested Set Model

Tags: java, mysql, database

Here is what I have:

- A table contain  records for issues property and hierarchical data(Nested Set Model)

What I want is change parent node property according to direct child property: like if all children property `isBlue ==1` then the parent node property should be `isBlue =1`

What I have done:

- Load the database into an list of objects. :(

What I got stuck:

- Load the list above to an effective container. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141099/how-to-display-a-tree-from-the-information-stored-in-database) , but it ain't work correctly and efficiency (because I have like ~1 million rows)
- Loop all the leaf node to check the property then change the parent accordingly (due to the above step not done).

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: 1. would you tag your DBMS? 2. please explain more about (according to child property)? direct children or all children in any levels? 3. can you use Stored Procedures or Functions? or you just want to do it in Java?

Comment: Hi; I updated the question for the info you need:
- I use mysql.
- I only care for direct children; but recursively from the bottom. Like the domino.
- I'm not familiar with Stored Procedures or Functions, but I'm willing to learn if it makes  the task easier.